# Running an asynchronous function within a Cloud Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to implement the Speech-to-Text API in this tutorial using Cloud Functions (python)

[Speech-to-Text long running](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize)

The one implemented here is an asynchronous, long running function. My aim is to have the Cloud Function download an audio from a site, write it to S3, then calls the Speech-to-Text APIs client function on that S3 location of the audio to return a transcibed text. Here is the shortened code from the tutorial:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1 as speech

client = speech.SpeechClient()
# storage_uri = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/brooklyn_bridge.raw'
# some configuration
audio = {"uri": storage_uri}
operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
```

However, in cases where the audio is too long, it won't fit even the maximum timeout in the Cloud Function and I get timeout in logs. The `client.long_running_recognize` was probably finished by Speech-to-Text API but the Cloud Function can't wait for it. What should I do in this case? Is using the `asyncio` library in Python a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions currently have a maximum timeout of up to [9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout).

You could use other GCP services that can perform longer operations. For example, App Engine Flexible has a [response time limit of 60 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled#response_limits_2) or App Engine Standard with basic scaling which has a [response time limit of 24 hours](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-instances-are-managed#timeout)